# Create navigation panel with managed bean to fill content panel

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF web application tied to a database. I have a left div panel for navigation
and a right div panel for content. I am able to fill the left div panel with `<h:commandLink>`s for book chapters. However, I am unsure how to wire the `<h:commandLink>`s to fire a bean method to call the database and fill the right div panel with the desired content.

This is the left div panel for navigation `nav.xhtml`:

```
<ui:composition>
    <h:outputText value="Navigation"/><br/>
    <ui:repeat value="#{tocBean.getTOC()}" var="TOC">       
        <li>   
            <h:form>
                <h:commandLink action="#{contentBean.getContent()}"> #{TOC}   
                    <f:param name="id" value="#{TOC}" />  
                </h:commandLink>  
            </h:form> 
        </li>   
        <!-- NewLine --> 
        <h:outputText value="&#10;" />
    </ui:repeat>  
</ui:composition>
```

The `TOCBean` fills the list with book chapter names. I'm trying to execute the backing bean method `#{contentBean.getContent()}` with the selected chapter name and fill the right div panel in `content.xhtml`.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you might want to use `outputLink` instead of `commandLink`.
With `outputLink`, you would produce a `HTTP-GET` parameter which you can access from your bean. Depending on this parameter, you can select the right `chapter` to display.

Comment: You forgot to tell about the concrete problem. E.g. is the action invoked or not?

Comment: @Aquillo it could be a POST request to execute an ajax update too.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I know, though since there was no mentioning of any ajax, nor any ajax attribute, I do not think that OP was trying to handle this with Ajax. Doesn't mean ajax shouldn't be the way to go here.